# Why can I not express the limit of infinite list in terms of filter condition in list comprehension?

Tags: haskell

In my Haskell program, I want to have an expression, in essence, equivalent to the following

```
cList = [i | i <- [1 .. ], i <= 5]
```

but it seems that the evaluation of `cList` will not terminate, producing

```
[1, 2, 3, 5
```

in ghci session, but never return, and the CPU of my computer kept running.

but the following equivalent will terminate as expected:

```
bList = takeWhile (<= 5) [1 ..]
```

What's wrong with the expression `cList` as infinite list compression with a filter condition?
 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How do you know there are no numbers less than 5 that come after 5? List comprehensions can't know that: they're not specialized to numbers. So it keeps searching forever, because there might be more values out there. If you know it will never succeed, you have to say so, by using a different tool.

Comment: Thanks! I was wrong assuming list comprehension understand the semantics of the generator, the number range.